Erro while converting Java POJO to Avro GenericRecord
I am trying to convert the Java POJO class into Avro format to send the data to the Kafka message broker using KafkaAvroSerializer.
I am facing the below error while converting the Java POJO class to Avro GenericRecord. The error I am facing is
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/avro/AvroParser$Feature (Module "deployment.MyAppModule.ear:main" from Service Module Loader): com/fasterxml/jackson/core/FormatFeature

The code that I am trying to use here is
public static GenericRecord convertPojoToGenericRecord(String schemaPath, MyMessageClass message){
  InputStream inStream = MyAppClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaPath);
  Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().setValidate(true).parse(inStream);
  AvroSchema avSchema = new AvroSchema(schema);
  AvroMapper avroMapper = new AvroMapper();
  final byte[] bytes = avroMapper.writer(avSchema).writeValueAsBytes(message);
  GenericDatumReader<Object> genericRecordReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(avSchema);
  return (GenericRecord) genericRecordReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null));
 } 

The exception is coming while executing below statement
  AvroMapper avroMapper = new AvroMapper();
The maven dependencies that I am using here are
jackson-dataformat-avro
jackson-core
jackson-databind
jackson-annotations
jackson-jars-json-provider
jackson-datatype-joda

The version for all the above dependencies is 2.9.10.
The application is a legacy application. I cannot change or upgrade the version for the Jackson libraries as these libraries are being used in other modules.
The application is getting deployed into JBoss server (version 10).
When I tried to get more details about the dependency tree, I found the jackson-dataformat-avro is using old dependency of jackson-databind with version 2.5.4
Any help related to this is appreciated.
Thanks,
Avinash

Since, your application legacy one, you can create one library that
converts JSON to different avro schema using gradle-avro-plugin framework.
Then you can integrate the library with your app. I think this is better
and more flexible.
